# Error occur if I use base class to define a key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I get an error for define `DbGeography` in EF6 (i don't have this Error in EF5) entity type if I use it from base class to define key:
for this class :

```
public class University
{
    public int UniversityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

university class mapping:

```
class UniversityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<University>
{
    public UniversityMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("University");
        this.HasKey(u => u.UniversityID);

    }
}
```

everything is correct and EntityFramework does it correctly, but if I change class to :

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int UniversityID { get; set; }
}
public class University:BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Data.DbGeography: : EntityType 'DbGeography' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DbGeographies: EntityType: EntitySet 'DbGeographies' is based on type 'DbGeography' that has no keys defined.

!!!???
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `DbGeography` class?

Comment: I am guessing you are using spatial types from Sytem.Data.Entity.dll instead of the ones that are defined in EntityFramework.dll. With EF6 you don't need the reference to the System.Data.Entity.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you accidentally erased `public int DBGeographyID{ get; set; }` property in the `DBGeography` class?

[Update]

Ha! Saw something in the net. Maybe you are using the wrong namespace.

Instead of `System.Data.Entity.Spatial` you might be using `System.Data.Spatial` instead. I saw it in this [link](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/650).

Comment: DbGeography is spatial data in System.Data.Spatial namespace i can't define key.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Ues System.Data.Entity.Spatial instead of System.Data.Spatial

Comment: But System.Data.Entity.Spatial is in EntityFramework.dll. You're telling me I have to add a reference to Entity Framework in my POCO Entities class library!?

Comment: @KellySandwiches Yes, that seems to be the case. I had my POCOs in a separate project. I needed to remove the reference to System.Data.Entity.dll and add one to EntityFramework.dll (and then adjust the namespaces in the using directives). Using DbGeography effectively ties the POCOs to EntityFramework.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, EF is getting confused because the name of the key doesn't match the name of the class it's defined in. It might seem obvious, `UniversityID` exists in a class called `University`, but it wasn't *defined* in that class, so perhaps EF is missing it.

Stick a `[Key]` on the `UniversityID` property and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i mapped this class in other class (edit post)